# BeautifulSoup Finviz

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Sorry for taking your time, I'm just learning beautifulsoup and I want to create a dataframe which will copy the table from this [URL](https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,sh_curvol_o500,sh_price_o3,sh_relvol_o1,sh_short_o10,ta_pattern_wedgedown&ft=3&o=-change)

```
import pandas as pd

# To extract fundamental data
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}


base_url = 'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=cap_smallover,sh_curvol_o500,sh_price_o3,sh_relvol_o1,sh_short_o10,ta_pattern_wedgedown&ft=3&o=-change'
html = requests.get(base_url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(html.content, "html.parser")
main_div = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'screener-content'})
table = main_div.find('table')
sub = table.findAll('tr')
rows = sub[5].findAll('td')

data = []

for row in rows:
    link = row.a
    if link is not None:

        data += link.get_text()

print(data)
```

But what I get is this:

```
['1', '1', 'A', 'P', 'I', 'A', 'g', 'o', 'r', 'a', ',', ' ', 'I', 'n', 'c', '.', 'T', 'e', 'c', 'h', 'n', 'o', 'l', 'o', 'g', 'y',
```

and so one.

How may I save all this data to the list so next I may create a dataframe close to the finviz screeners table? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem in your code is:

```py
data += link.get_text()
```

The `+=` syntax does not work in Python like this. To add an element to a `list`, we can use `L.append(obj)`. So your code can be changed to:

```py
data.append(link.get_text())
```